# Define multiple variables inside while loop

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, variable

I'm currently reading from a csv file and iterating through each line to define variables in some columns that I will use later.

Say my csv file looks as follows:

```
Column1,Column2,Column3,Column4,Column5
String1,String2,String3,String4,String5
...
```

```shell
while IFS= read -r line
do
  VARIABLE_1=$(awk -F"," '{print $2}')
  VARIABLE_2=$(awk -F"," '{print $4}')
  curl -XPUT <url_1>/2
  curl -XPUT <url_2>/4
done
```

For some reason, it's picking up only `VARIABLE_1` instead of both variables. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Your code does not appear to refer to `$line` anywhere within the body of the loop

Comment: Because awk can read input from stdin, the first awk is slurping up all the rest of whatever you pipe/redirect into the while loop.

Answer (score 4):

bash's `read` command can split a line into an array of fields:

```bsh
while IFS=, read -r -a fields; do
  var_1=${fields[1]}     # bash arrays are indexed from zero
  var_2=${fields[3]}
  # ... use those variables
done < file.csv
```

That's not a *true* CSV parser: it will not respect a comma within a quoted field. With bash version 5.1 you can do

```bsh
BASH_LOADABLES_PATH=${BASH/bin/lib}
enable -f csv csv

while IFS= read -r line; do
  csv -a fields "$line"
  # ... use the fields array
done < file.csv
```

---

If you want to ignore the header row from your CSV file, you can do this:

```bsh
{
    read headers
    while IFS= read -r line; do 
        # do stuff
    done
} < file.csv
```

Comment: +1.  BTW, the `csv` loadable built-in might not be in the same package as bash.  On Debian, for example, it's in the optional `bash-builtins` package, which contains source code and executables for loadable built-in versions of csv, cut, head, rm, basename, ln, tee, and many other programs (most of which are minimalist versions of those found in GNU coreutils).

Comment: Also, on my system (debian sid), `BASH_LOADABLES_PATH=${BASH/bin/lib}` doesn't work. I have to hard-code it to `BASH_LOADABLES_PATH=/usr/lib/bash`.   Maybe because this machine was built long before the (rather pointless & misguided, IMO) /bin & /usr/bin merge.  My bash is /bin/bash, the loadable built-ins are in /usr/lib/bash.

Comment: I've never been completely confident with ${BASH/bin/lib} other than "works for me". Building bash [from source](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git) builds the loadables,